# Laravel Collective does not work

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.1

I am trying to learn Laravel using the Laracasts and it's very interesting.
In the step of creating forms, I would like to use Laravel Collective. So I went to the website http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html and tried what's written, but I get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

Here's my code:

**app.php**

```
'providers' => [    
    ...
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    ...
],
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class
],
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
},
```

Any idea what I can do to solve my problem?

Comment: Just to confirm, did you run `composer update` after modifying your `composer.json` file, and do the `Html` and `Form` aliases exist in your `app.php` file?

Comment: Yes I did a composer update. I edited the topic to add the aliases.

Comment: You might have some caching going on. Run `composer dump-autoload --optimize`, `php artisan clear-compiled`, and then `php artisan optimize`. If that doesn't work, go ahead and delete the `composer.lock` file, and the entire `vendor` directory. Then run `composer install`.

Comment: While doing php artisan clear-compiled, I get the error: $ php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146

Comment: It now works. I tried again, from the very beginning. I probably have forgotten to do composer require laravelcollective/html or did in the wrong step.